# Running Visual Basic Script as a Scheduled Task asks how I want to Open the File

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have created a task in the Task Scheduler that is supposed to execute a .vbs file that I wrote. The problem is that each time the service runs, rather than actually executing the code, I am asked how I want to open the file. How can I stop this? Please do not suggest batch files; I cannot use them for this.

[image]

The command line is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\Malwarebytes Task Scheduler Instructions\Batch Files\MalwarebytesScanAndUpdate.vbs"`.

The vbs file's code is...

```
Dim shell
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "MalwarebytesUpdate.bat"
WScript.Sleep 300000 'Sleeps for 5 minutes.
shell.Run "MalwarebytesScan.bat"
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to "execute" the .vbs file in Task Scheduler? (What's the command-line you're using?)

Comment: @KenWhite I just set the task's action to run the script.

Comment: What did you set the "task's action" to do **specifically**? When you clicked "Action->New", and it asked you for "Program/Script", what does it show after you browsed for the script and selected it?

Comment: @KenWhite See edit. I apologize for not understanding the request.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (and the details). Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but why aren't you using MalwareByte's built-in scheduler? It includes "Schedules automatic scanning" as part of its functionality. I'll post an answer with a suggested solution.

Comment: @KenWhite I know about the Malwarebytes built-in scheduler, but it doesn't offer me the customization that I need.

Comment: OK, fair enough. (As I said, just curious.) I've posted an answer that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have [`wscript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875526%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) configured as the default association for .vbs files instead of [`cscript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff920171%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). You can check at a command prompt, using [`ftype`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771394%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). On my plain Win7 64-bit Pro machine, it produces the following (which would indicate mine is configured to `wscript.exe` as well):

```
C:\>ftype VBSFile
VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

Change the **Program/script** entry, and add `cscript.exe` to the beginning, so the full entry would read (all on one line, of course):

> cscript.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\Malwarebytes Task Scheduler Instructions\Batch Files\MalwarebytesScanAndUpdate.vbs"

If the Task Scheduler complains about `cscript`, change it to

> "%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\Malwarebytes Task Scheduler Instructions\Batch Files\MalwarebytesScanAndUpdate.vbs"

If this doesn't work, cut the full pathname (again, including quotes), and paste it into the edit control labeled **Add arguments (optional):**.

You can also set `cscript` to be your default script processor at the command-line (although I'd discourage it unless you're sure that's what you want to do):

```
C:\>cscript /H:Cscript
```

Note you'll have to do so at a command prompt opened as an administrator ("Start", type "Command", right click on "Command prompt" and choose "Run as Administrator" from the context menu), and execute the above from there. You'll get something like this as the output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cscript /H:CScript
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

The default script host is now set to "cscript.exe".
```

If you decide to undo it, repeat the above and use `/H:WScript` instead.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cscript /H:WScript
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

The default script host is now set to "wscript.exe".
```

Do they really include a single quote in their folder name? That's pretty nasty, IMO. :-)

Comment: Using the entry you gave me, I get a message saying that the system cannot find the specified file. As for your suggestion about moving the filepath into the argument box, the scheduler did it automatically. If you need, I will post a screenshot of the entire error.

Comment: Sorry. Did you copy/paste? There's an erroneous space (typo) between `cscript.` and `exe`. I'll fix it (as well as posting an alternative means of specifying it).

Comment: No, I copied the one above that did not have the extra space between `cscript.` and `exe`.

Comment: :-) I just corrected it, so if you're seeing it without the space you're seeing the correction. Check the entry again in Task Scheduler. I also added an alternative that includes the full path (the one with `%SystemRoot%` in it).

Comment: Based on the command prompt capture you included, you're missing the double-quotes around the path to the script file. Check the path and filename to the script *very carefully* in the Task Scheduler dialog. If Windows can't find it, you've missed something.

Comment: Now that I've added those double-quotes, I am getting an error saying `There is no file extension in C:\Program`.

Comment: I can't physically view your screen to see what the problem is; you're going to have to do that yourself. You have something wrong with the path and filename to the script file. If you can't figure it out, clear it and start over, or delete the task and start from scratch. I can't debug remotely on your system; you're going to have to take it upon yourself to **carefully** review what you've entered and find the mistake.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will let you know what the end result is when I have fixed the problem. Thanks for all of your help. I will come back and accept your answer A.S.A.P. For the record, I just checked, and the filepath is correct. I will look over it later though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with single quotes in file or folder names on Windows, since single quotes aren't quoting characters.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I didn't say there wasy anything wrong with it. I said it was *ugly*.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is really old, but I just had the same problem and solved it in the following way, whether or not it's the "correct" way, other's can judge.

I was trying to schedule a script **C:\reminder.vbs** to run at a specific time and had the same issue where I could run it by double clicking in explorer no worries, but when the task ran it asked what I wanted to open it with. I resolved the issue by changing the scheduled program/script from **C:\reminder.vbs** to **wscript.exe "C:\reminder.vbs"**

So it perhaps doesn't really explain why the initial problem was occurring, but it does make the script run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well, on a fairly "clean" Windows Server 2012 R2 system, with only Firefox and WinRAR installed in addition to various Windows roles and features.

The scheduled task was set to run something like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\example\Example\Sample App\Directory\example.vbs"

The above was the result of selecting the .vbs with the Browse function of the Task Scheduler Properties dialog.

Running the task manually with the "[x] Run only when user is logged on" option opens the "How do you want to open this file?", prompting to select one of Firefox, IE, Notepad, etc.

Note that without the above setting, it only silently gives "The operation was canceled by the user. (0x800704C7)" Last Run Result. So I hope that other people looking for this error can now find this thread and try the "[x] Run only when user is logged on" option to see if they have this exact problem.

assoc .vbs gives:
.vbs=VBSFile

ftype VBSFile gives:
VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

I tried setting the current directory in the "Start in" option, but that did not help either.

The solution in my case was to not simply add the current directory, but to also edit the Program/script string that the Browse button had set.

This:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\example\Example\Sample App\Directory\example.vbs"

had to become:

example.vbs

And the "optional" Start in field had to be set to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\example\Example\Sample App\Directory\

Other variations, e.g. the path with quotes, or Program/script with the path, did not resolve.

Comment: Epic, worked for me. Thanks for submitting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you're prompted how you want to open the (VBScript?) file, but the screenshot of the error message you posted says that your VBScript cannot find the batch script it's trying to run. These are two different issues and not related to each other.

Prompts about how you want to open a particular file are usually caused by a missing association of the file's extension with an executable program, or by a missing default action.

This might indicate malware on your system, because by default the extension `.vbs` is associated with `wscript.exe`.

You can either use `assoc` and `ftype` to verify the association:

```
C:\>assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile

C:\>ftype vbsfile
vbsfile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

or you can directly check the respective registry settings, which should look like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
+-.vbs : (Default)  REG_SZ  "VBSFile"
|
`-VBSFile
  `-Shell : (Default)  REG_SZ  "Open"
    `-Open
      `-Command : (Default)  REG_EXPAND_SZ  "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

---

The error message from your screenshot

> The system cannot find the file specified.

is generated, because your VBScript cannot find the batch file `MalwarebytesUpdate.bat` in the current working directory. There are three ways to fix this:

1. Set the working directory of the scheduled task (field *Start in (optional):*) to the folder containing the batch file.
2. Have your VBScript change the working directory to the folder containing the batch file.

   ```
   shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Program F...ructions\Batch Files"
   shell.Run "MalwarebytesUpdate.bat"
   ```
3. Specify the full path to the batch file in the VBScript.

   ```
   shell.Run """C:\Program F...ructions\Batch Files\MalwarebytesUpdate.bat"""
   ```

   Note that in this case you need double quotes around the path, because it contains spaces!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I needed to add `shell.CurrentDirectory`. I assumed that I would be okay without it because the batch files are in the same folder as the script, but apparently it does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I was running bubbles.scr(the bubbles screen saver) through bubbles.vbs in the task scheduler because Windows 8.1 won't run it otherwise.

Mine won't run because the bubble.vbs was in a directory with a long file-name, when I had earlier used 'JV 16' to disable long file-names to speedup my computer.

I also had wscript.exe set as the default program to open .vbs file with (type: ftype vbsfile (at the command prompt to find the default program association)

I had to specify cscript.exe as the program/script to be run in the task scheduler and specify the the path to the vbs script(j:\bubbles.vbs) as the argument (without the quotes).

I also had to either enable the long file-name support or choose a directory name of 8 or fewer characters (j:\Bubbles Screen Saver\bubbles.vbs to j:\bubbles.vbs) .

[I use the bubbles screen saver to protect my screen when I read books over an extended duration because you can see through the bubbles during brief pauses
]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same thing once. I found this from one of the MS forums.

A VB script can run directly from Windows task schedule.  In the task scheduler,  select Add a new scheduled task.  Following the prompts, browse to select your .vbs file.  Name your task and select your schedule to run the task daily and select the time of day to run.  It works just the same as if you want to schedule .Bat file.
Use the absolute file path in the command. 
Or call vbs file from a .bat file.
cscript //nologo c:\test.vbs

Comment: The question says he's already done this, and it isn't working properly. There's even an image now.

Comment: I have already done all of this. The problem is that when the task starts, rather than actually running it, it just asks me how I would like to open the file. I am trying to use a `vbs` file instead of a batch file because I do not want any consoles to be visible when the task is running.